# "Unexpected end of JSON input" when creating a telegram bot (the JSON file is just to store data and it's empty)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, debugging

I tried googling that and searching in here, didn't find anything useful, so PLEASE don't close this topic, just a please. I tried debugging the code, it's referring to the `userStorage.JSON` file, although it's empty and the purpose of it is just to store data. Here's the two pieces of code:

```
class PersistentMemoryStorage extends Telegram.BaseStorage {
constructor(userStoragePath, chatStoragePath) {
    super();

    this.userStoragePath = userStoragePath;
    this.chatStoragePath = chatStoragePath;
    this.isClean = false;

    this._storage = {
        userStorage: require(userStoragePath),
        chatStorage: require(chatStoragePath)   
    };
}
```

```
PersistentMemoryStorage = require('./adapters/PersistentMemoryStorage')
storage = new PersistentMemoryStorage(
    `${__dirname}/data/userStorage.json`,
    `${__dirname}/data/chatStorage.json`
```

)

If you can help me out please. I'm creating a telegram bot.

Comment: First observation: `userstorage.JSON` is not the same as `userstorage.json` on many systems. Second observation: if a script complains about the JSON input ending unexpectedly it would help to provide the JSON file in question.

Comment: Alright, I'm sorry but I just saw this.
It worked. The .json file was completely empty, I had to enter a "{}" inside it to work. Thanks anyways :)